# jQuery Mobile Browsers (Chrome, Samsung Intenet) return empty value of input - why?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

My code returns empty value of an input even the input is not empty.

In Deskop Chrome there is not a problem... but when I run it on Android Chrome or Samsung Internet, it returns empty value.

My code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('input#chw').on('blur', function() {
      if ($(this).val() && parseInt($(this).val()) > 0) {
        alert($('input#iosm').val()); //HERE IT RETUNS EMPTY ON MOBILE BROWSERS!!!
      }
    })

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="send_cmsg">
  <table class="main_tab gener_tab">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="gt3c">
        <td class="first">Put any numeric value to this input</td>
        <td class="scnd"><input type="tel" id="iosm" value="" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="chw gt3c">
        <td class="first">Then put some value here and blur input<br>On Deskop it returns value... on Mobile Devices in return empty value</td>
        <td class="scnd onnrr"><input id="chw" type="tel" data-nl="een kind" data-nl2="kinderen" data-en="one child" data-en2="children" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Does somone know how it could fix on mobile browsers?

I added an additional code to alert the value of field "on blur"... and when I blur $(this) input... it shows the correct value:
[image]
But after I go to the another field and after blur I want to get the value of the previous value... it retuns empty value...
[image]

I tried already to clear cache, but the value of any field is empty... but on Deskop Chrome/Edge it returns everything perfect:

[image]
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Putting the jQuery "ready" handler inside a DOMContentLoaded handler doesn't make sense; that's exactly what the jQuery mechanism does.

Comment: Also it works for me on Android Firefox.

Comment: That's really strange because I checked it on both browsers and it works as well... but on my website... exactly the same code does not work...  in console there is not any error... etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem... The form was opened in a modal... and in the mobile version  browsers a function which was responsible to create the modal... crated it twice... so there were two forms with the same inputs (`dobule IDs`). So it worked perfect for `$(this)`, but for `certain ID` it didn't... because the script didn't know which value has to take... so it returned empty value.

Thanks anyway!